# Run single test in three different browsers using selenium grid

Tags: selenium

I have test and I want to run it in firefox, chrome, IE simultaneously (all three browsers uses same code) using selenium grid.  is that possible? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you sucessfully run it in one browser before? Which language do you use? Selenese command or any other programming language?

Comment: I was able to run the code successfully in individual browser. using java language.

Comment: Have you tried triggering the test 3 times? What happened?